# How to get php variable from js function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to use these php variables that come from mysql database and send an email. when the user hits the Request button it goes to myFunction()

test.php file:

```
    $x = db_query('SELECT * FROM test_site_database.names');

    foreach($xx as $item) {
      if($item) {
        if ($item->name == "Paul"){
        $dname = $item->name; 
        $state = $item->state;
        $city = $item->city;
    }
      }
    echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>' . $dname . '</td>'; //prints Paul
         echo '<td>' . $state . '</td>'; //prints CA
         echo '<td>' . $city . ' </td>'; //prints LA
         echo '<td><button onclick="myFunction()">Request</button></td>';
         global $y; 
         $y=dname; 



         <script>
         function myFunction() {
         <?php
         global $user;
         $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
         $subject = $user->name;
         $txt = $y; //
         $headers = "From: test@email.com";
         mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
         ?>
         }
         </script>
```

So in the email I receive after I hit request is the user name and $dname(full name of that person) HOWEVER there are 10 Paul's in my database I only get the info from the last inserted from the database but it's a table with 10 Paul's and I hit request on lets say row 3 I want to get that data emailed instead of the last Paul in the db.

any ideas or other approaches?
Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript cannot call PHP functions. You need to send a request to the php via ajax or a new http request. The request can then send the email.

Comment: inside you javascript function try to make Ajax Call and send data through it!

Answer (score 0):

Sending a variable from an backend scripting language to a front-end scripting language is quite simple. There are many different ways to do this.

**Method 1:**

Using PHP, create a javascript block that you will insert early in your page. Early enough that the variables will be available in the other scripts where they are needed. And simple way could be to insert it in the  section of the page before loading the other scripts.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My awesome page</title>
  <script>
      var myJsVar1 = <?= $somePhpVar1 ?>;
      var myJsVar2 = <?= $somePhpVar2 ?>;
      var myJsVar3 = <?= $somePhpVar3 ?>;
  </script>
  <script src="someAmazingScript.js"></script>
  <script>
    console.log("My variable 1 value is ", myJsVar1);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    console.log("My variable 2 value is ", myJsVar2);
    alert(myJsVar3);
  </script>
<body>
</html>
```

**Method 2**

If you have a lot of stuff to send from the backend to Javascript, you can store the values in a JSON object directly in the head tag to make it available everywhere when the page is loaded. Then you access it by parsing JSON content. In the following example, the script tag with the id appData must be generated entirely from PHP and printed in the head section of the page. If you use json_encode with an associative array, it will give you a string that is a valid JSON object with the nested keys inside of it.

```html
<script id="appData" type="application/json">
 { 
   myVar1: 'value1',
   myVar2: 'value2',
   myVar3: 'value3'
 }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var appData = JSON.parse($('#appData').html());
        console.log("Values received from php", appData);
        console.log("myVar1 = ", appData.myVar1);
     });
</script>
```

Based on how your HTML is being generated, I am sure you can figure out the easiest way to add a script tag in the page's head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function myFunction(str) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str; //now I get the correct data inside str from $dname
```

I passed the php variables like this:

```
echo '<td><button onclick="myFunction(' . $dname . ')">Request</button></td>';
```

and this way you can start using all the correct data on whatever you need to do with it in the function.